# Twitter timelime within Sinatra app

Tags: jquery, ruby, model, twitter, sinatra

Previously I have used jquery to intergrate a twitter feed into my app using version 1, this is now deprecated and v 1.1 is to be used. So from what I have read I need to request via Oauth to get access to the timelines. This is correct yes?

With this i need to save the tweets to a model and then render pull the tweets from there into my app.

Could anyone give some pointers please on making a start on this within a sinatra app, I havent used models within a sinatra app before and not sure where to begin..Has anyone successfully done this or know of any examples/tutorials on how to achieve?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

For models I strongly recommand [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/docs/), it goes very well with sinatra, and has a powerful `auto_update!`. Really powerful and easy-to-use.

And I think you're pulling the tweet to your app right? so maybe the `github-service` stuff won't help you much, it's doing the post tweet stuff.

If you're developing an app not only for your own usage, you should read twitter's official document about [oauth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter), and you need to do `Obtaining a request token`, and `Redirect user`, and have an endpoint to receive twitter's callback and obtain the finally useful access token. That's needed for pull your tweets.

If just for your own usage, you should read [this document](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom) and as it said twitter automatically generated an access token for your own test usage. Just copy-paste it and use~

Hope these will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Look into github services. They're well maintained, Sinatra based, and have examples on how to integrate much about everything you can think of:

https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/master/lib/services/twitter.rb

(It won't always be the way you'd want them on your end, but at least you get working code to base your own work on.)